# How should I display single-data-object fetched by API in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning React-Native and trying to display user profile on profile screen.

Displaying a list of objects obtained from the server is pretty straightforward, but I am confused on how do I display a single-object that my API-call fetches.

This is my fetched object data output which I get when I do `console.log(getProfileApi.data)` right before displaying it.

```
Object {
  "email": "user1@gmail.com",
  "first_name": "User",
  "gender": "Male",
  "id": 2,
  "last_name": "1",
  "profile": Object {
    "address": null,
    "city": null,
    "country": null,
    "dob": "2021-11-01",
    "profile_pic": "http://192.168.0.218:8000/media/profile/user1_profile.jpg",
    "title": null,
    "zip": null,
  },
  "user_type": "Owner",
}
```

This is how I am trying to display the fetched data, **but the data is not displayed**.

```
<FlatList
  // getProfileApi contains the response from server which is shown above
  data={getProfileApi.data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Text>{item.email}</Text>
  )}
/>
```

How do I extract the data and display it. Is there any other component to use instead of Flat-List to display a single-object data?

Comment: You usually use FlatList to display a list of objects/records of same type. In this case, you only seem to have a single object and you already know the keys it would contain. So why not just render them directly with Views and Texts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `FlatList` is used to display the data of the array. It is usually used to display big lists, like products list in an e-commerce app, users lists, posts, etc. To display simple data as you have, you can use `ScrollView`. Follow the below approach to display your data in `ScrollView`.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const YourScreenName = () => {
  // declare state variable to handle loading UI
  // set initial value to true, so when screen load initially it display loading
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true); 
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = useCallback(() => {
    setLoading(true); // Start the loader, So when you start fetching data, you can display loading UI
    getProfileApi().then((data) => {
      setUser(data);
      setLoading(false);
    }).catch((error) => {
      // display error
      setLoading(false); // stop the loader
    })

    // or your any data fetching query
    // setUser(getProfileApi.data);
    // setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={styles.container}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
    >
      {
        isLoading && (
          <Text>Loading</Text> 
        );
      }
      {
        !isLoading && user && (
          <View>
            <Text>Email : {user.email}</Text>
            <Text>Name : {user.name}</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});

export default YourScreenName;
```

Comment: If I display Image using `<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: .data.profile.profile_pic }} />` I am getting render error. Any Idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a flat list you can directly render the UI component and make it's content dynamic just like below

```
<Text>{getProfileApi.data.email}</Text>
```

there is no need for a flat list here because it is used to render a list of data but for a single data set, you can directly use it in your UI.

Comment: If I use this technique, when I try to display Image like `<Image
    style={styles.image}
    source={{ uri: getProfileApi.data.profile.profile_pic }}
  />` I get error

Comment: Use Like this 
<Image     style={styles.image}     source={{ uri: getProfileApi?.data?.profile?.profile_pic }}   />
it will check if value you are accessing is exist or not

Answer (score 0):

First create a state like this

```
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
```

then you have to set your array in the state after you have fetched the data from your api instead of directly calling getProfileApi which looks like a function

```
setMyArray(yourresponsearray);
```

then inside your Flatlist component you can pass that state inside the data prop

```
<FlatList
  data={myArray}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Text>{item.email}</Text>
  )}
/>
```